# ReactJs - Passing function as a prop. Warning: invalid prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a working example of passing function from parent to child as a prop and then calling it from the child.

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-pond-y2h4v

However, while it works fine , react doesnt like it and in the console it throws warning : Invalid value for prop `matrixfunc` on  tag.

Any suggestions what could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question itself. If the external link is deleted or modified, the question will have no future value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
<Card {...rest} className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
```

`Card` component from Material UI does not have `matrixfunc` property and you are trying to pass it with spread operator.

Answer (score 2):

Here `matrixfunc` is in the `rest` object:

`const { className, ...rest } = props;`

And then it's passed to the `Card`:

`<Card {...rest} className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>`

And I assume that `Card` just pass all props to `div` element. But `div` doesn't know anything about `matrixfunc` so that gives you a warning.

You should exclude `matrixfunc` from `rest`:

`const { className, matrixfunc, ...rest } = props;`

and use it:

```
const changeState = () => {
  matrixfunc(props);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is:

1. `React.setState()` -> you should define empty string `React.setState('')`. // This will remove error BUT
2. Here is next problem. In your App1.js you should paste in your `matrixfunc(props.matrixvalue)` // NOT `matrixfunc(props)`

Whole logic was a bit dirty but it should work as expected :)